# How to capture video without saving?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-capture

I have made a custom camera and from that, I want to capture a video and send it to the next VC.

I tried doing it the following way, but this way The video is being saved in the gallery. I don't want that to happen yet.

So my question is how do I only capture a video using custom camera, without saving it?

```
  func setupSession() -> Bool {

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

    // Setup Camera
    let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)!

    do {
    
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
    
        if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            activeInput = input
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error setting device video input: \(error)")
        return false
    }

    // Setup Microphone
    let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)!

    do {
        let micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone)
        if captureSession.canAddInput(micInput) {
            captureSession.addInput(micInput)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error setting device audio input: \(error)")
        return false
    }


    // Movie output
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
    }

    return true
}

func setupCaptureMode(_ mode: Int) {
    // Video Mode

}

//MARK:- Camera Session
func startSession() {

    if !captureSession.isRunning {
        videoQueue().async {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}

func stopSession() {
    if captureSession.isRunning {
        videoQueue().async {
            self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }
}

func videoQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
    return Dispatch.DispatchQueue.main
}

func currentVideoOrientation() -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    var orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation

    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .portrait:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        case .landscapeRight:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
        default:
             orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
     }

     return orientation
 }


@IBAction func startCapture(_ sender: Any) {
    if cameraButton.titleLabel?.text == "record" {
        cameraButton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
        startRecording()
        runTimer()
        
    }
    else {
        
        stopRecording()
        timer.invalidate()
        cameraButton.setTitle("record", for: .normal)
    }
}

func tempURL() -> URL? {
    let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString

    if directory != "" {
        let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
        return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    }

    return nil
}

func getPHAssetfromURL(url:URL,onCompleted:@escaping (_ phAsset:PHAsset)->Void){
    var phAsset:PHAsset?
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
            phAsset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).lastObject
            onCompleted(phAsset!)
            
        }
    }
}

func startRecording() {

    if movieOutput.isRecording == false {
    
        let connection = movieOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)
    
        if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
            connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
        }
    
        if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
            connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
        }
    
        let device = activeInput.device
    
        if (device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported) {
        
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
               print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
            }
        
        }
  
        outputURL = tempURL()
        movieOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
    
        }
        else {
            stopRecording()
        }
   }

 func stopRecording() {

   if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
       movieOutput.stopRecording()
    }
}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {
    

}

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    if (error != nil) {
    
        print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    
    } else {
    
        let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
        
        
        let url = videoRecorded

        getPHAssetfromURL(url: url) {(phAsset) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //let vc = segue.destination as! VideoPlaybackViewController
                
                let vc : VideoPlaybackViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DisplayVC") as! VideoPlaybackViewController
                
                //let vc = VideoPlaybackViewController()
                        vc.videoTrimmerDelegate = self
                        vc.phAsset = phAsset
            vc.videoURL = url
                  vc.assetURL = url.path
                
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to save it. Videos cannot be captured in memory.

Comment: can I override the updated video in the gallery? Like I want to capture a video then apply filter and then save it

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by gallery. You are saving into the temporary directory.

Comment: I mean iPhone gallery 'Photos'

Comment: But you are the one who is calling getPHAssetfromURL which copies the saved video from the temporary directory into the photos library. If you don't want to do that then don't do it. You have free will.